# Firebase Phone Auth redirect to browser?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I send OTP through Firebase it redirects to the phone browser. In the past, this could be fixed by device verification API. But now it has been depreciated.

**My dependencies**

```
    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics")
implementation 'com.google.android.play:integrity:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'
```

I have enabled the **Play integrity Api**

[image]

I have even added **Sha1 and sha256** ( debug and release ). And added the file to the project.

[image]

I have even **uninstalled and reinstalled** the app. and even change the **build variant to Release**, but it is not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the SafetyNet app verification that was recently deprecated, the Play Integrity API requires your app to actually be released on the Play Store. Play Integrity relies on the versions of your application that it has access to in Google Play to correctly attest your verification attempt.

I assume it was introduced for security reasons, as (in theory) an app that's actually released on the storefront should be verified and free of any rootkits etc. Keep in mind that your app doesn't have to actually be publicly available - although it can't be just a Draft. You can see the Google Play release statuses, here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en#zippy=%2Capp-status

Comment: I link play integrity from the play console. And on internal testing download Apk. It worked.